# Счетчик кликов по ссылке

Tags: php

Добрый день! Имеются статьи с ссылками, нужно считать каждый клик по ссылке и записывать в БД. Поле для подсчета кликов называется view, поле где прописана ссылка на статью, называется adres. Кто знает помогите пожалуйста. Вот кусок кода php: 
                <?

```
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE cat='$cat'",$db);

            if (!$result)
            {
            echo "<p>Запрос на выборку данных из базы не прошел. Напишите об этом адмистратору afonya94@bk.ru <br> <strong>Код ошибки:</strong></p>";
            exit(mysql_error());
            }

            if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)

            {
            $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            /*Счетчик просмотров*/
            $new_view9 = $myrow["view"] + 1;
            $update = mysql_query ("UPDATE new SET view='$new_view9' WHERE id='$adres'",$db);
            /*Конец счетчика*/

            do 
            {
            printf ("<table align='center' class='post'>

                     <tr>
                     <td class='post_title'>
                     <p class='post_name'><a href='%s' target='_blank'>%s</a></p>
                     <p class='post_adds'>Автор урока: %s</p></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                     <td class='post_view2'>

                     %s 
                     <p class='info'>Все подробности здесь: <a href='%s' target='_blank'>%s</a></p>
                     <p class='post_view'>Просмотров: %s</p></td>
                     </tr>

                     </table><br><br>",$myrow["adres"],$myrow["title"],$myrow["author"],$myrow["description"],$myrow["adres"],$myrow["title"],$myrow["view"]);
            }
            while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));

            }

            else
            {
            echo "<p>Информация по запросу не может быть извлечена, в таблице нет записей</p>";
            exit();
            }

            if(isset($result) && !empty($result))       
            ?>
```

Comment: счетчик отмечен комментарием в php, не работает, как только не пробывал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно такой записи:

```
$update = mysql_query ("UPDATE `new` SET `view` = `view` + 1  WHERE `id` = '".$adres."'",$db);
```

И выбросьте подальше уроки Попова, иначе дела не будет!

---

> если у Вас будет свободное время, не
> могли бы это показать)

@DimasikYES, добавляете id, если такая ссылка на странице в единичном числе, или класс, если таких ссылок несколько. При генерировании ссылок, добавляете атрибут **data-id**, где значением будет id этой статьи или чего у вас там. В общем, значение, которое вы используете в запросе в переменной *$adres*. Должно получится что-то в этом роде:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="updCount" data-id="100500" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

На этой же странице, подключаете файл с js-кодом (*напр., script.js*), в котором пишите следующий код:

```
function createRequestObject() {
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest === 'undefined') {
    XMLHttpRequest = function() {
      try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); }
        catch(e) {}
      try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); }
        catch(e) {}
      try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
        catch(e) {}
      try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
        catch(e) {}
      throw new Error("Этот браузер не поддерживает XMLHttpRequest.");
    };
  }
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
function updCount() {
  var data = this.dataset,
    http = createRequestObject(),
    url = 'ajax_handler.php',
    params = 'pid=' + data.id;
  http.open('POST', url, true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
  http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      alert(JSON.parse(http.responseText));
    }
  }
  http.send(params);
  return false;
}
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.updCount');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
  links[i].addEventListener('click', updCount, false);
}
```

Теперь создайте файл **ajax_handler.php** с кодом:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pid']) && ($pid = (int)$_POST['pid'])){
  // тут ваше подключение к БД
  $query = "UPDATE `new` SET `view` = `view` + 1 WHERE `id` = ".$pid;
  $res = mysql_query($query, $db);
  exit(json_encode($res ? 'Всё гуд!' : 'Хьюстон! У нас проблемы!'));
}
```

Всё. Би хеппи.

P.S. И хорошо бы переключаться на нормальные инструменты для работы с БД: MySQLi, PDO. Что, собственно, и [советуют разработчики](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) (*читаем текст, выделенный красным*).

Comment: К сожалению не считает(

Comment: @DimasikYES, к счастью, оно считает, **если** всё остальное написано правильно. Проверьте переменную $adres, убедитесь, что имя таблицы и поля написаны верно и вообще, доходит ли дело до запроса.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Я в начале не много не уточнил ссылка введет на другой совсем сайт, не связанный с моим. Это влияет?

Comment: @DimasikYES, конечно влияет. По клику, без предотвращения стандартного действия, отправляйте ajax-запрос, на апдейт своего счетчика.

Comment: Спасибо большое) Я новичок в этом деле, если у Вас будет свободное время, не могли бы это показать) Сколько уже читаю разных статей, не могу понять и найти.

Comment: @DimasikYES, в своем проекте используете jQuery? Если да, то какая версия?

Comment: Не использую.

Comment: @DimasikYES, дополнил в ответе.